# OAuth Official application

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, oauth-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [authentication in own mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224264/authentication-in-own-mobile-app)

I've successfully implemented OAuth2 to secure access to my API.
I still have a question.

I'm actually developing an official app, and obviously I must skip the step "authorize this app to access to my data" (btw, Facebook and Google don't have this step for their products).

I could use the classic authentification method (like on my website which uses the API), but I think I must be able to revoke an official app (in case of a stolen phone for example).
Google and Twitter offer this possibility to revoke the official app. I suppose they are using OAuth with their official apps too.

**My question is:**
How can I identify an official application (in order to give it on demand an access token) since I think the source code is not very safe (hackers can use reverse engineering)?

To sum up, I can't store a secret key in the app source code (not safe), but I don't want that my app has to be accepted by users.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance, and please excuse my poor english.

Comment: Just to clarify - is your OAuth authentication happening on the client side via JavaScript?  i.e. The client has the secret tokens in order to perform auth requests?

Comment: I would like to set a consumer_secret and a consumer_key in order to identify the official app.

The app should contact the API server and say "hey, I'm official, you can trust me I've got the secret, user doesn't have to accept me"
I don't know where to store these variables, I only see Javascript (full javascript app => Phonegap), but Javascript is totally unsafe. 

Is there a way to secure it?